# Can't Get Cloud Function to Run Every 15 mins using PubSub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I've been trying to run a regular cloud function to send a notification to appropriate users that runs every 15 minutes.

I've so far been unable to get the function to run repeatedly (it seemed to run once, and that's it), or to see logs of how far it had been completed.

It seems like I can create the schedule within the function, by using firebase-functions.pubsub.schedule, or I can create a job using Cloud Scheduler that also has the same frequency and triggers a message to that topic.

I have not created a job using Cloud Scheduler since it seems like creating the schedule within the Node.js code is recommended everywhere I look. Based on the setup below, am I missing anything obvious that should get the function to run on an every 15 minutes schedule?

### Steps I've done:

1. Create a pubsub topic
2. Eventarc trigger based on google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished looking at that pubsub topic
3. Main code in my cloud function (Node.js 20) uses functions.pubsub.schedule() to generate events.

#### Eventarc Trigger

[image]

#### Cloud Function Code

Note: `sendDailyNotifications` is listed as my entrypoint

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

firebase.initializeApp();

// create the database
const db = firebase.firestore();

exports.sendDailyNotifications = functions.pubsub.schedule('15 * * * *').onRun(async (_) => {
    functions.log('Daily Notification Cloud Function Started');
    await checkAndSendNotifications();
});

async function checkIncompleteTasks(userId) {
  // Function Code
}

// Function to check for incomplete habits
async function checkIncompleteHabits(userId) {
  // Function code
}

// Function to send notifications
async function sendNotification(userId) {
  // Function code
}

function currentTimeRoundedToNearest15Minutes() {
    // Function code to get the time for the notification
}

// Firebase Cloud Function logic
async function checkAndSendNotifications() {
  const currentHHMM = currentTimeRoundedToNearest15Minutes();

  // Query users who match conditions and are due for notifications
  const usersRef = db.collection('usersCollection');
const query = await usersRef.where('dailyNotificationTime', '!=', null)
                     .where('dailyNotificationTime', '!=', '')
                     .where('notificationsAllowed', '==', true);
  
query.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const userData = doc.data();
            const notificationTime = userData.dailyNotificationTime;

            // Compare notification time and current time
            if (currentHHMM === notificationTime) {
                // The current time matches the notification time
                // Send the notification or take action here
                sendNotification(doc.id);
                functions.log(`Sending notification to user: ${doc.id}`);

            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with your CRON job inside the line:

`functions.pubsub.schedule('15 * * * *')`

This will result in **"at minute 15"**, that's why it's only running once.

You might want to change that to:

`functions.pubsub.schedule('*/15 * * * *')`

This will result in **"at every 15th minute"**, which should run your function every 15 minutes. Check this [online tool](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*) for the Cron format.